# Bulk Read form Amazon Redshift

Tags: batch-processing, amazon-redshift

We have a use case where we have to combine data from 3 tables in redshift.the data size is around 1 million records.

1. The first table contains client details  - tabl1
2. Second table contains visits - table2 (M2O relation to table1)
3. table contains events- table3 (M2O relation with table2)

Now we have to aggregate these 3  tables and prepare a record based at the  visit level such that it contains the client details from table1, visit details from table2 and all the events attributes of table3.

What is the  best way to read data in above format from redshift using batch job?

Comment: Are you asking for assistance in writing the SELECT... JOIN statement, or are you asking about how to run queries as batch jobs?

Comment: @John Rotenstein how to run queries as batch  job.

Comment: Redshift behaves as a normal SQL database. You can run commands using the pg_sql command-line. What have you tried so far?